# Unable to get where clause to work with text containing a single quotation

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I am working with some geo-spatial (string) data that i have been saving into an SQL server database, whenever my data has had a single quote within the string i am saving, i have tried to escape this by padding the single quote. Though this allows me to save the text into my database, when i try to use a where clause to find locations which have been had an escape sequence applied to them, the where clause does not seem to pick them up.

For example 
`SELECT * from tb_test WHERE Address = 'Abbey Gardens, St John''s Wood, London, NW8';`
Will produce an empty table, even if this record exists. The only want i have been able to get this to work was by using `LIKE` to match the pattern of my text which does not include the quotation (see below).
`SELECT * from tb_test WHERE Address LIKE 'Abbey Gardens'`

Is there any reason as to why SQL does not pick up on the full Address ? and if so how can i get it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `SELECT * from tb_test WHERE Address = 'Abbey Gardens, St John''s Wood,
>   London, NW8';` Will produce an empty table, even if this record exists.

The quotes are proper in the literal so it seems the actual column value does not match the literal value. This could be due to trailing whitespace (e.g. tab, newline, etc.). Check the raw binary value of the column for unexpected characters:

```
SELECT CAST(Address AS varbinary(MAX)), *
FROM tb_test
WHERE Address LIKE 'Abbey Gardens%';
```

Comment: I can confirm that the binary of what is found in my column does not match the binary i get when i use my select query (```select CAST('Abbey Gardens, St John''s Wood, London, NW8' AS varbinary)```). But i can not figure out. I have copied the address from the column and it seems to match the address i am using in my query (no trailing whitespaces or newlines).
Binary for address in the columns = 

0x41626265792047617264656E732C205374204A6F686E27277320576F6F64

Binary for select query address = 

0x41626265792047617264656E732C205374204A6F686E277320576F6F642C

Comment: @KvothesLute, you need to specify a length for the `CAST` to avoid truncation to the default of 30 bytes. Try casting as varbinary(MAX) to get the complete value.

Comment: as suggested i tried the select query with used ```varbinary(MAX) ``` and the binary is still different from that in the columns.

Comment: @KvothesLute, yes, the different value explains why the value isn't returned. What is the binary column value with the varbinary(MAX) cast?

Comment: the binary column value with varbinary(MAX) cast is 0x41626265792047617264656E732C205374204A6F686E27277320576F6F64
the varbinary(MAX) cast for the select query where text is 
0x41626265792047617264656E732C205374204A6F686E277320576F6F642C204C6F6E646F6E2C204E5738

Comment: The actual value in the database has 2 consecutive double quotes (0x2727), perhaps due to a data entry error. This  `WHERE` clause should return the row: `WHERE Address = 'Abbey Gardens, St John''''s Wood'`

Comment: I do not get any errors when i input my addresses as all i do is escape sequence the single quotation, do you have any idea why this is happening, perhaps there is a better way to escape the single quotations ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204675/discussion-between-dan-guzman-and-kvotheslute).